# Multiple parameters error while creating function in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

I created a function, now rather passing static value I want to add parameter in the function but after calling function it start throwing an error:

> Procedure or function dbo.hello has too many arguments specified.

Function :

```
Create Function dbo.hello
    (@InputstartDate Date, @InputendDate Date)
Returns @attendanceTemp table(STUD_NAME VARCHAR(50), 
                              ATTD_DATE DATE , 
                              attd_DATEs DATE,
                              Attendance VARCHAR(20))
As
Begin
    Declare @startDate DATE 
    SET @startDate = @InputstartDate

    Declare @endDate Date
    SET @endDate = @InputendDate

    Declare @dateDifference INT
    SET @dateDifference = DATEDIFF(day, @startDate,@endDate) ;

    Declare @count INT
    SET @count = 0

    DECLARE @myTable TABLE (STUD_ID int,
                            countdd int,
                            STUD_NAME varchar(50),
                            AttDate Date
                           )

    While @count <= @dateDifference
    Begin
        Insert Into @myTable (STUD_ID, countdd, STUD_NAME, AttDate) 
        Values (1, 123, 'HAIDER', @startDate)

        Set @count = @count +1
        Set @startDate = DATEADD(day, 1, @startDate)
    End

    Insert Into @attendanceTemp 
        Select 
            tb.STUD_NAME, ATTD_DATE, tb.AttDate,
            Case
               When att.DETAIL Is Null
                  Then 'ABSENT'
               When att.DETAIL = 'ATTENDACE' 
                  Then 'PRESENT' 
            End As Attendance 
        from 
            @myTable tb
        Left Join 
            ATTENDANCE att on tb.AttDate = att.ATTD_DATE
        Where 
            att.STUD_ID = 1 or att.STUD_ID IS NULL 

    Return
END
```

Calling the function:

```
select * 
from dbo.hello('2014-04-01', '2014-04-10');
```

Error:

> Procedure or function dbo.hello has too many arguments specified

Comment: I cannot repro this issue, the function works fine. Are you running the select statement against the right server and database?

Comment: `select  * from sys.objects where name = 'hello'`, `sp_helptext 'dbo.hello'`

Answer (score 0):

Possibly you first created the function with only one parameter.
Then made changes to the 'create function' script, and forgot to deploy?

I would;

```
1. DROP FUNCTION dbo.hello
2. CREATE FUNCTION dbo.hello, with you script
3. Try executing your function again.
```

The function seems to work fine (Though I cannot run a full test due to not having table 'ATTENDANCE')